# admob integration on libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently working on an android game using libgdx, the game is almost complete but I want to integrate admob ads to my game. I've already tried all the codes available and still can't get it to work.

This is the code I'm using:

```
/*public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new ZBgame(), config);
    }
}*/

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-6916351754834612/3101802628";
      private static final String GOOGLE_PLAY_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TheInvader360";
      protected AdView adView;
      protected View gameView;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
       // cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        AdView admobView = createAdView();
        layout.addView(admobView);
        View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        setContentView(layout);
        startAdvertising(admobView);
      }

      private AdView createAdView() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        return adView;
      }

      private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
        gameView = initializeForView(new ZBgame(), cfg);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
        gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return gameView;
      }

      private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      }

      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) adView.resume();
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) adView.pause();
        super.onPause();
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
      } }
```

The error I get when I run the app from eclipse, it says unfortunately your game gas stopped, but it worked flawlessly without the admob code.

The logcat is also included as text:

```
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409): Process: com.kilobolt.zombiebird.android, PID: 9409
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409): java.lang.VerifyError: com/kilobolt/zombiebird/android/AndroidLauncher
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-13 20:19:23.363: E/AndroidRuntime(9409):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The system prevented you from including pictures where text is more appropriate. **Never** upload a picture of code or log text, even if you would have the rep to do so.

Comment: Alright thanks Anthon, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @SahilSethi try to add only the AdView. If it works, then there will be a conflict between the views.

Comment: i just tried to only display the AdView but still it says your game has stopped and the logcat displays: 03-16 19:30:20.520: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(2634): A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.